# Issue with 'non real value' error while solving for time in a model parabolic zip line.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, mathematical-modeling

I am modelling the time it will take for a person to slide down a zip line from a fixed start to end point in zip lines of different shapes. The models will be performed with straight line, parabolic curve, elliptical arc and cycloid.

I am able to solve for the parabolic and elliptical curve; however, I am encountering issues while solving the time taken for the parabolic curve. For starters, I derive the equation for time from mechanics as well as conservation of energy. This equation assumes that gravity is the only force that acts on the object and that friction is negligible.

[image: The equation for time...]

As the start point and end points of my model is fixed, I first find the equation of a parabola that passes through the points A (start) and B (end).
Therefore, I am left with this equation of a parabola which is the model for my zip line:

[image: The equation of the resulting parabola]

Now, when I try to find the time taken by the passenger using the equation for time which is the first image; an error arrises on my calculator that says 'Non real values'. **I do not understand why this error comes.** The calculation is shown below:

[image: Calculation to find the time]

**Why does the error come on the calculator?** The exact same formula works without showing the error for the straight line and elliptical arc. What is making it show 'Non real values' for this integral? **What can be done in order to attain a value for time as it is crucial for my investigation?** I need the travel time in seconds it takes for the passenger on this particular zip line.

Comment: The equation you are using is wrong. Just translate the curve up by some constant value. The time should not change. The derivative of $y$ is fine, but you still have a $y$ at the bottom, which will not cancel. So $T$ is dependent on adding an extra constant to $y$, which is physically incorrect.

Comment: @Andrei Is y=0.000174x^2 correct? By what constant should I translate the curve?

Comment: The reason for the “non real value” is that your integral include the value $x=0$ (and other values close to $0$).  When $x=0$ the denominator is clearly negative and you’re taking the square root of a negative number.  This is literally a non-real value.

Comment: The formula is wrong. How was it derived? Let's say $y=x$, with $x_1=1$ and $x_2=2$. Calculate $T$. Now choose $y=x+1$. It should take the same amount of time, but your integrand is always smaller. Or take $y=x-2$, and then your integrand is complex. But the time should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From conservation of energy $$v^2=2g(y_1-y)$$ Then your formula becomes
$$T=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{\frac{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}{2g(y(x_1)-y(x))}}dx$$
The formula is valid only for $y<y(x_1)$, meaning that you can never go higher than the initial point (if you started with zero velocity). You notice then that if $x_1=0$ in $y(x)=0.000174x^2-0.6852$ it means that the object starts at the bottom of a parabola, and it will not be able to go up (no energy). In order for the problem to work, you need to start at $x_1\ne 0$ and have $y(x_2)\le y(x_1)$.